# Lookup in 'dictionary' with pandas dataframes instead of for loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

One that acts as a dictionary with the columns:

- "Score"
- "Translation"
- A number of columns with different variations of the word

Another one with one column: "sentences"

The goal is to:

- split the sentences into words
- lookup the words in the dictionary (in different columns) and return the score
- give the score of the word with the highest score as a "sentence score"

```
df_sentences = pd.DataFrame([["I run"], 
    ["he walks"], 
    ["we run and walk"]], 
    columns=['Sentence'])

df_dictionary = pd.DataFrame([[10, "I", "you", "he"], 
    [20, "running", "runs", "run"], 
    [30, "walking", "walk", "walks"]], 
    columns=['score', 'variantA', 'variantB', 'variantC'])

Out[1]: 
   Sentence           Score
0  "I run"             30
1  "he walks"          40
2  "we run and walk"   "error 'and' not found"
```

I got quite far using for loops and lists, but that is quite slow and so I am looking for a way of working that let me do all/most of this within the pandas dataframe.

This is how I did it with a for loop:

```
for sentence in textaslist[:1]:
words = split_into_words(sentence)[0] # returns list of words
length = split_into_words(sentence)[1] #returns number of words
if minsentencelength <= length <= maxsentencelength: # filter out short and long sentences                                                     
    for word in words:
        score = LookupInDictionary.lookup(word, mydictionary)
        if str(score) != "None":
            do_something()
        else:
            print(word, " not found in dictionary list")
            not_found.append(word)      # Add word to not found list     
                                                   
print("The following words were not found in the dictionary: ", not_found)
```

using

```
def lookup(word, df):
if word in df.values:                                                       # Check if the dictionary contains the word
    print(word,"was found in the dictionary")
    lookupreturn = df.loc[df.values == word,'score']                         # find the score of each word (first column)
    score = lookupreturn.values[0]                                           # take only the first instance of the word in the dictionary
    return(bare)
```

The problem is that when I use the pandas "merge" function, I need to specify in which column to look with the right_on left_on parameters and I can not seem to find how to search in the whole dictionary dataframe and return the first column with the score in an efficient way

Comment: Please provide a small set of sample data as text that we can copy and paste. Include the corresponding desired result. Check out the guide on [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Comment: I added some sample data, hope it is more clear now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you modify your dictionary in this format `[word, score]` then you can split the the sentences by word, merge with the dictionary then `groupby` and sum the score.
Since this uses pandas functions it should be fast enough for your dataset, not sure if it's possible to make it faster than this.

### tl;dr

```py
df_sentences = pd.DataFrame([["I run"], 
    ["he walks"], 
    ["we run and walk"]], 
    columns=['Sentence'])

df_dictionary = pd.DataFrame([[10, "I", "you", "he"], 
    [20, "running", "runs", "run"], 
    [30, "walking", "walk", "walks"]], 
    columns=['score', 'variantA', 'variantB', 'variantC'])

df_dictionary = pd.melt(df_dictionary, id_vars=['score'])[['value', 'score']]

df_sentences['words'] = df_sentences['Sentence'].str.split()
df_sentences = df_sentences.explode('words')

sentence_score = df_sentences.merge(df_dictionary, how='left', left_on='words', right_on='value')[['Sentence', 'score']]

sentence_score_sum = sentence_score.fillna('NaN').groupby('Sentence').sum()
# or
sentence_score_max = sentence_score.fillna('NaN').groupby('Sentence').max()
```

---

## Break down

to modify the dictionary into `[word, score]` format you can use [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) like so

```py
df_dictionary = pd.DataFrame([[10, "I", "you", "he"], 
    [20, "running", "runs", "run"], 
    [30, "walking", "walk", "walks"]], 
    columns=['score', 'variantA', 'variantB', 'variantC'])
df_dictionary = pd.melt(df_dictionary, id_vars=['score'])[['value', 'score']]
```

which will give you

```
     value  score
0        I     10
1  running     20
2  walking     30
3      you     10
4     runs     20
5     walk     30
6       he     10
7      run     20
8    walks     30
```

Now to work with Sentences, we want to be able to extract each word on it's own while keeping track of the main sentence.
let's add a new column that contains the words as a list

```py
df_sentences = pd.DataFrame([["I run"], 
    ["he walks"], 
    ["we run and walk"]], 
    columns=['Sentence'])

df_sentences['words'] = df_sentences['Sentence'].str.split()
```

which would give us

```
          Sentence                 words
0            I run              [I, run]
1         he walks           [he, walks]
2  we run and walk  [we, run, and, walk]
```

Then [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the words

```py
df_sentences = df_sentences.explode('words')
```

which give you

```
          Sentence  words
0            I run      I
0            I run    run
1         he walks     he
1         he walks  walks
2  we run and walk     we
2  we run and walk    run
2  we run and walk    and
2  we run and walk   walk
```

now we [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) it all together

```py
sentence_score = df_sentences.merge(df_dictionary, how='left', left_on='words', right_on='value')[['Sentence', 'score']]
```

giving us

```
          Sentence  score
0            I run   10.0
1            I run   20.0
2         he walks   10.0
3         he walks   30.0
4  we run and walk    NaN
5  we run and walk   20.0
6  we run and walk    NaN
7  we run and walk   30.0
```

Now we can combine `groupby` with `sum` to sum by score for each sentence

> Note that pandas would treat `NaN` as `0.0` which we don't want, thus we are filling na using `fillna` to the string of "NaN".

```py
sentence_score_sum = sentence_score.fillna('NaN').groupby('Sentence').sum()
```

giving you

```
                 score
Sentence
I run             30.0
he walks          40.0
we run and walk    NaN
```

Your question said you wanted to give the highest word score to the sentence but your expected output was showing the sum, if you need the max score then it's a simple

```py
sentence_score_max = sentence_score.fillna('NaN').groupby('Sentence').max()
```

giving you

```
                 score
Sentence
I run             20.0
he walks          30.0
we run and walk    NaN
```

> Note: This solution relies on having **UNIQUE** sentences, if you have duplicate sentences you would either `drop_duplicates` before starting or you could apply `reset_index(drop=False)` before the merge to keep the index and then `groupby` on the old index instead of the `Sentence`.

Comment: are you talking about filtering the dataframe and then appending the columns at the bottom so that I essentially get 1 huge list with 2 columns like in @kentaro s example?
That might be a good approach indeed. Some example code how to do the split and append would be nice :)

Comment: yes, look into the `melt` method it might help.  also if you want an example I can probably come up with something

Comment: @theotherguy I've updated my answer with code and a breakdown of how it works. Note that this would give you a `NaN` for when a word is missing and wouldn't tell you which words were missing, but you can get those missing words from the intermediate steps right after the merge

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the breakdown! This is exactly what I was looking for. My hat off to you good sir

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following regex approach:

```py
# Store scores using index
score_dict = {x:0 for x in df_sentences.index}

# Loop through each row in the score df (df_dictionary):
for row in df_dictionary.values:
  # Access the score
  score = row[0]
  # Access the words & convert to a pattern
  words = "|".join([re.escape(x) for x in row[1:]])
  pattern = re.compile(r"\b(" + words + r")\b", re.I|re.M)
  
  # Loop through each row in the main df (df_sentences):
  for idx, row in df_sentences.iterrows():
    # Find the number of matches in the sentence
    matches = pattern.findall(row["Sentence"])
    # Multiply to get the score
    n_score = len(matches) * score
    # Store it using the index as key
    score_dict[idx] += n_score

# Now, add the dict as a column (or map it back to the main df) 
df_sentences["score"] = df_sentences.index.map(score_dict)

    Sentence    score
0   I run   30
1   he walks    40
2   we run and walk 50
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my data is huge and with for loops it takes ages to run over all the iterations.

Comment: You could try to convert to convert to a function and map `df_dictionary` to the function while applying to `df_sentences`. Frankly, what you're trying to do is a compute intensive problem.

Comment: Unless you don't care about multiple words, in which case, you can do `df_sentences.Sentences.str.replace(word, n)` replacing `word` and `n` for words and scores....

Answer (score 1):

Do you care about duplicates?  If I had a string like "I I I," that'd technically be 30 points.

Also, is there a particular reason you're using a dataframe to store your scored words?

Quick & dirty using set intersections to efficiently remove duplicates:

```
dictionary ={
"I": 10, "you": 10, "he": 10, 
"running": 20, "runs": 20, "run": 20, 
"walking": 30, "walk": 30, "walks": 30
}

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Sentences":[
        "I run and he walks",
        "We walk and he runs",
        "I Run you run he runs",
        "I run he runs",
        "I I I I I"
    ]})

def split_score(sentence):
    x = sentence.split(' ')
    x = set(x) # remove duplicate words
    y = x.intersection(set(dictionary.keys())) # find matches in the dictionary
    z = x.difference(set(dictionary.keys())) # find words outside the dictionary
    if len(z) > 0:
        score = -1 # If non-dictionary words are found, fail
    elif len(z) == 0:
        score = sum([dictionary[word] for word in y])
    return score

df['Points'] = df['Sentences'].apply(lambda x: split_score(x))
df
```

[image]

Comment: Also, do you WANT it to fail if there's a word that isn't in the dictionary?

Comment: The reason for using dataframes is that the dictionary is a huge csv file. But the way you do it and like @Jimmar also noted, combining the columns with the variations in one column/dictionary/list might be a good approach. Now I just need to find out how to get that done :-D

And yes, I want it to fail if a word is not found in the dictionary. It should then be added to the "not found" list

Comment: note that `apply` is a bit slow, look into using pandarallel to do it in parallel and speed it up.

Comment: Will "help" will trigger "he" in this solution?

Comment: This isn't using regex, it's comparing entire strings to one another. One confounding factor would be punctuation, though.  If there are any commas or periods, this will fail.  I updated my answer to include the failure case. Also I set the failure case to -1 to ensure you don't convert the whole column into pandas objects or strings. This will make it easier to handle the result later on.